# Deformation of an elastic ball

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, contact-mechanics

Suppose a free sponge ball is being compressed, due to applying a known force in a specific direction.

The ball's shape will be distorted. Given are the direction of the applied force, as well as its magnitude.

Can I calculate the deformation that the ball experiences in any other direction?

Does it depend on some tensor?

Comment: You likely need more information to constrain the problem. Is the force applied at a point, along contact with a plane, or just a general force on each volume element like gravity? And is the ball held in place by something, or freely accelerating? With enough boundary conditions I think one can solve the elasticity equations to get the solution, but it is very dependent on what the situation actually is.

Comment: If the ball is compressed between two plane frictionless walls and the gravitational force is negligible, the deformation of the ball and the stress distribution within the ball can be determined based on the 3D version of Hooke's law and the stress-equilibrium equation.

Comment: Elasticity theory is your friend here - there are many excellent books and notes out there.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you mean something similar to what @ChetMiller proposed in the comments. That is, a sphere between two place frictionless walls or, equivalently, a sphere with two diametrically opposing force.

If we express this problem in spherical coordinates the stress, strain and displacement are independent of the azimuth. That means that it can be expressed in axisymmetric solid spherical harmonics. The expressions are rather long, so if you are interested you could read reference 1.

**Note:** A foam is probably not well represented by this model since it will present non-linear behavior. Probably, a hyperelastic behavior comes into place.

#### References

1. Hiramatsu, Y., & Oka, Y. (1966, May). Determination of the tensile strength of rock by a compression test of an irregular test piece. In International Journal of Rock Mechanics and Mining Sciences & Geomechanics Abstracts (Vol. 3, No. 2, pp. 89-90). Pergamon.

Comment: How is the strain independent of the azimuth? There is compression perpendicular to the planes and expansion parallel to them.

Comment: @nasu, The functions are independent of the azimuth not the components of the tensors.

Comment: What functions? You say " strain and displacement are independent of the azimuth".

Comment: @nasu, yes those functions are independent of the azimuth. The problem has a rotational symmetry thus you can't identify the azimuth 0 with any direction in the equator of the sphere. You do have $u_\phi$ and $\epsilon_{\phi\phi} components, though.

Comment: Which functions?

Comment: @nasu, displacements, strains and stresses.